# KStream leftJoin KStream with the same Key

Tags: java, apache-kafka, left-join, apache-kafka-streams

I have the problem taht i try to leftjoin 2 Streams. mergedKey has 100+ 
listings with the same key and DataStream has just 1 listing with the same key as mergedKey. I want in the endStream Value from mergedKey Merged with DataStream.

```
      //get DataStream 
        final KStream<String, GenericRecord> DataStream = builder.stream("Datastreams");
        // Transform merged to Equals Keys to DataStream.Iot
        final KStream<String, GenericRecord> mergedKey = mergedFoIObs
                .map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(value.get("Datastream").toString(), value)); 
        // Join the DataStream with MergedStream


        final KStream<String, String> mergedFoIObsData = mergedKey.leftJoin(
                DataStream,
            (value, data) -> {
                try {
                    if(data != null{
                        value.put("Datastream", data.toString());
                        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(value.toString());
                        return jo.toJSONString();}
                      return null



                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;

            }, JoinWindows.of(10000));
```

But My problem is that in the Endstream I get just 1 listing with the right values and the other listings has null as values.

Taht means that data is null after the first "round".

When i transfrom DataStream to a KTable I have the problem taht i get right listing but just 37 listings so 60 are Misssing.

I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

For the KStream-KStream join, is depend on the timestamps of the record if they join or not. Check out this blog post for more details: https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/

For the KStream-KTable join, it depends when the KTable record will be loaded into the KTable -- Kafka Streams tries to synchronize the loading based on timestamps, but it's a best effort approach. Thus, it can happen, that some KStream records are processed first, while the KTable is still empty. Only after the KTable records was processed (ie, the KTable as updated and contains the record), the consecutive KStream records will join successfully.

Note, that next Kafka release 2.1 will improve this timestamp synchronization and provide stronger guarantees, and users will even be able to configured how strict the guarantees should be.

Answer (score 0):

"Furthermore, for each input record of this KStream that does not satisfy the join predicate the provided ValueJoiner will be called with a null value for the other stream."

So you should not return null when the data (right value) is null, you should return value (left value).

[kafka docs link on leftJoin](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#leftJoin-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueJoiner-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.JoinWindows-)